# How is the differential form of Gauss Law used?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

How is the differential form of Gauss's Law $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot{\bf E} =  \dfrac{ρ}{ɛ}$ used? What I mean is, where am I measuring $E$ and what is $ρ$ in this context?

Comment: http://physwiki.ucdavis.edu/Fundamentals/10._Fields/10.7_Gauss'_Law_In_Differential_Form

Comment: Hi Jayanth, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Like count_to_10 suggested, this information is found in many basic textbooks and similar resources. What didn't you understand when you tried to look it up? If you can give detail on that, it will help make this a better question.

Comment: I answered your question, however, you should have researched it further. Please ask more well organized questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me clarify you what divergence actually is.

Consider an arbitrary finite volume $V$, whose surface is $S$, in a vector-field $\bf h$. Then total flux emerging from $S$ is given by $$\text{Net flux from the surface} = \int_S \mathbf{h}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a}.$$ 
 Divide $V$ into two parts: $$V = v_1 +v _2\,.$$ Now the flux out of volume $v$ is given by : $\displaystyle{\int \mathbf{h}\cdot~\mathrm  d{\bf a}_V = \int \mathbf{h} \cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a}_{v_1} + \int \mathbf{h}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a}_{v_2}}\;.$ Start dividing the volume into $N$ parts so that $V = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N v_i\,.$ So, the net flux out of volume $V$ is $$\int \mathbf{h} \cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a}_V= \sum_{i=1}^N \int \mathbf{h} \cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a }_{v_i}$$. This is a macroscopic quantity. However, we want to find some microscopic property associated with a certain point along with a neighbourhood of infinitesimal radius; in order to do this, we make $N \to \infty$ so that $\mathrm d{\bf a}_{v_i} \to 0$. Let the flux out of such infinitesimal volume $v_i$ is $\int\mathbf{h}\cdot \mathrm d{\bf a}_i$. This quantity is surely approximating to $0$. But if we take the ratio of the flux divided by the volume it encloses, we can get a finite quantity. This is what we call divergence. $$\text{div} \mathbf{h}_i \equiv \lim_{v_i \to 0} \frac{1}{v_i} \int \mathbf{h}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a}_{v_i} .$$ So, *divergence of a vector is a local property that measures at a point the flow of $\bf h$, **per unit volume**, in the neighbourhood of this point*.

So, $$\int_S \mathbf{E}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \int_{S_i}\mathbf{E}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a_i} = \int_V \text{div} {\bf E} ~\mathrm dv\,. $$ But we already know, $$\int_S \mathbf{E}\cdot ~\mathrm d{\bf a} = \int_V \frac{\rho(v)}{\varepsilon_0}~\mathrm dv\,.$$ Comparing the two equations, we get $$\text{div} \mathbf{E} =\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot{\bf E} =  \dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$$ (in Cartesian coordinates).

---

### Tl;dr:

What does $\text{div} \mathbf{E} = \dfrac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$ mean?

It means that the flux of electric field per unit volume centered at a certain point is equal to the charge density $\rho(v)$ enclosed by the infinitesimal volume around that point divided by $\varepsilon_0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring $\vec E$ due to the continuous volume charge distribution enclosed by the Gaussian surface. $\rho$ refers to the volume density of charge of the continuous charge distribution.